# Sometime publishing fails during Transporting phase with error "Internal Server Error"

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

Sometime publishing fails during Transporting phase with error:

> Could not transport tcm_0-333793-66560.Content.zip using HTTPS,cause: "Internal Server Error".

In cd_transport log, the error is:

> 2012-10-30 06:34:16,778 ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - An unexpected error occurred while retrieving: "http://deployer/httpupload.aspx reason: Internal Server Error"
>
> 2012-10-30 06:34:16,793 ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to send TransportPackage to url: "http://deployer/httpupload.aspx cause: Internal Server Error"
>
> 2012-10-30 06:34:22,600 ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - An unexpected error occurred while polling: "http://deployer/httpupload.aspx reason: Internal Server Error"

After publishing again, I am able to publish the failed pages.

After setting the log level to "Debug" getting below information in cd_core.log file

```
      2012-10-30 11:47:39,260 ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to send TransportPackage to url: "http://deployer/httpupload.aspx cause: Internal Server Error"
      2012-10-30 11:47:39,260 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - "Connector is registered for reuse: HTTP[Password[******], UserName[server\tridion], URL[http://deployer/httpupload.aspx]] available: 1"
      2012-10-30 11:47:39,260 DEBUG ParallelDestinationWorker - Received item from transport destination: yyK/eL9dJ29chwTx2vRFrQ==
      2012-10-30 11:47:39,260 INFO  TransportItem - Received transport feedback, transport state is: failed=true for transaction: tcm:0-334545-66560
```

No information in cd_deployer.log file related to publishing error. It just says

```
      2012-10-30 11:58:23,249 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-334566-66560 control=COMMIT] to C:\Temp\tcm_0-334566-66560.Content\transaction.xml
```

Information in IIS log:

In HTTPUpload log file, I can see the log details with status as 200 , 401 and 500. 200 being in large scale but their are also details with the status as "401" and "500".

Error details are

```
       "2012-10-31 12:54:39 W3SVC1485900680 100.100.100.100 GET /httpupload.aspx fileName=tcm_0-337505-66560.state.xml&action=remove 80 - 192.168.168.14 - 401 2 2148074254"
```

Comment: You should check the cd_core.log and cd_deployer.log on the deployer machine. The transport log only tells you what the CM sees, namely that 'something is wrong'. Raise the log level if necessary (in the logback.xml).

Comment: Thanks Quirjin. I have set the log level to "INFO" and then checked the cd_deployer.log which is empty and cd_core.log does not contain any such information about publishing.

Comment: Hi Meenakshi. You need to set the level to "DEBUG" to get decent informations about why it fails.

Comment: Hi Meenakshi. It looks as if the HTTPUpload site is not reachable at all from the CM side. When you have this error then it's shut down, the URL is wrong or the deployer not set-up correctly. Can you even reach the http://deployer/httpupload.aspx URL from your CM machine? Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. HTTPUpload is reachable from the CM as all the pages are not failing and secondly the failed pages with this error are getting published after first or second try.

Comment: Hi Meenakshi. The logging that you're showing is related only to the Transport Service. You need to set logging to DEBUG on the HTTPUpload side because the information we get on transport side does not seem to be enough. Please set the logging on HTTPUpload side to DEBUG, make sure it's logged to a separate file and check if you get warnings/errors when publishing fails.

Comment: In HTTPUpload log file which was IIS logging, I can see the log details with status as 200 , 401 and 500. 200 being in large scale but their are also details with the status as "401" and "500". Error details are 2012-10-31 12:54:39 W3SVC1485900680 100.100.100.100 GET /httpupload.aspx fileName=tcm_0-337505-66560.state.xml&action=remove 80 - 192.168.168.14 - 401 2 2148074254

Comment: Hi Meenakshi. That is not the log that I was referring to. I was referring to the log file which is generated by your HTTPUpload (not by IIS) and that you can configure by going to the '/bin/config/logback.xml' file of that site (it's similar to the file with the same name from '/config' folder on the CM side).

Comment: Exactly! That was the gist of my first comment yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

It is related to maximum size limit on your deployer.Look at the deployer logs.
Hope by increasing maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength your problem get resolved.